# What am i doing wrong? cx_Oracle installation error

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, instantclient

Hi I'm trying to connect Python jupyter to my Oracle sql developer.
Please please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

1. Install cx_Oracle
   pip install cx_Oracle
   Success!!!
2. I went to Oracle Instant Client and downloaded Basic package instant client 21_3 version and unziped and saved in c drive
3. Copy the Oracle instant client 21_3 path and pasted in environment variable
4. Import cx_Oracle
   Conn=cx_Oracle(...details)
   Error is DPI-1047 Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library.

I honestly cannot tell what im doing wrong and all the tutorial videos are so confusing please please someone who already did this successfully please help me.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQLite?

Comment: The Windows cx_Oracle 'quickstart' instructions are useful: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/python/quickstartpythononprem.html  Also see the cx_Oracle documentation on initialization https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#using-cx-oracle-init-oracle-client-to-set-the-oracle-client-directory

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise cx_Oracle to tell it where the dependencies are. For example:

```
import cx_Oracle

CONFIG = {
    'user': 'hr',
    'password': 'oracle',
    'dsn': 'localhost/orcl'
}
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir='<your path>/instantclient_19_8')

with cx_Oracle.connect(**CONFIG) as conn:
```

...and so forth

Comment: Note that init_oracle_client() really only works on Windows and macOS.  On platforms like Linux you have to set the system library search path e.g. LD_LIBRARY_PATH or use ldconfig _before_ you run python.